# Indexing full column or substring

Tags: mariadb

I have a large mariadb table with millions of rows.  The basis for much of the data analysis will be on a 10 digit column like below.

```
4047535609
6099526199
6014157747
3045308020
```

For many of the queries, I only need the first 6 digits.  The plan is to index this column, but I'm curious whether it would make much/any difference to create an index of a substring, such as left(sku,6) or just index the whole column.  I should note that most of the queries will involve grouping of common first 6 digits.

HD space isn't really a concern, but with potentially 15-20 million rows, I'm curious about the cardinality of the index.

Edit:  I changed the column name to sku instead of id.  The id column is the primary key. The sku column is not unique.

```
id int(11) Primary Key
sku varchar(12)
rate decimal(5,2)
region varchar(24)
quantity int(4)
orderdate datetime
```

I expect most of the queries to involve grouping of common sku in relation to the other categories such as # of sku at n rate or x region.

Answer (score 0):

Plan A: index on virtual column `id6` defined to be `LEFT(id, 6)`.

Plan B: "prefix indexing": `INDEX(id(6))` -- this is frugal on disk space, but rarely beneficial.

Plan C: Simply use `INDEX(id)` (or `PRIMARY KEY(id)`??)

The question is missing a lot of details:

- Are the queries "point queries"?  That is, do you want to find the first sample item via `"404753"?  If so, Plan A, with`WHERE id6 = '404753' is probably the best.
- Do the queries need to do some form of "range", such as `WHERE id between "404700" AND "404987"`?  Plan B is terrible.
- Is `id` the `PRIMARY KEY`?  This implies uniqueness, and the existence of `PRIMARY KEY(id)`.  Plan C is the best, but to optimize point queries, requires `WHERE id >= '404753' AND id <= '40475359999'` (or something like that)
- etc.  (If you give us some more details, I may have more to say here.)